# Python login to webpage and get contents of session protected page

Tags: python, session, web, authentication, request

I have been googling for this problem for a week now.
The thing I want to achive is the following:

Send a POST request to the URL including the correct credentials.
Save the session (not cookie since my website is not using cookies at the moment)
With the saved session open a session protected URL and grab the contents.

I have seen alot of topics on this with cookies but not with sessions, I tried sessions with requests but seems to fail everytime.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [URL opener](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.build_opener). Here's a sample of how I've managed to do it. If you just want a default opener, use `opener=urllib.request.build_opener()`, otherwise use the custom opener. This worked when I had to log into a website and keep a session, using `URL` as your URL, `user` as user, `password` as password, all changed as appropriate.

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(http.cookiejar.CookieJar()))
pData=urllib.parse.urlencode({"identity":user,"password":password})
req=urllib.request.Request(URL,pData.encode('utf-8'))
opener.open(req)

req=urllib.request.Request(url)
response= opener.open(req)
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand this, I am using python 2.7