# Python: how to login to stockcharts and get contents of session protected pages?

Tags: python, session, authentication, passwords

I want to login to `stockcharts.com` webpage and then play with something available to its users after logged in.

Here is what I tried:

```
from requests import session

payload = { 'form_Name':         'Login',
            'zendesk_timestamp': '',
            'redirect':          '',
            'form_UserID':       'XXXX@YYY.com',
            'form_UserPassword': 'ZZZZ',
            'form_RememberMe':   ''
            }

c        = session()
this_url = 'https://stockcharts.com/scripts/php/dblogin.php'

c.post( this_url, data = payload )

request = c.get( 'http://stockcharts.com/h-hd/?GOOG' )
```

I then play with the fetched historical data.

I used `spyder`, and below are the error messages I got:

```
raise ConnectionError(e)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(
         host = 'stockcharts.com', port = 443 ):
         Max retries exceeded with url: /scripts/php/dblogin.php
         ( Caused by <class 'socket.error'>:
                  [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer )
```

I have been googling for its answer for a while, tried a few things like ( the code and title are actually "borrowed" from them )

[How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage)

[Python login to webpage and get contents of session protected page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080469/python-login-to-webpage-and-get-contents-of-session-protected-page)

I just cannot make it work for me. I use Python for some time but I think I am still somehow new to such kind of programming.

could anyone help me out? appreciate your help a lot!!

JW

Comment: Can you confirm, that your login-credentials are both correct and valid, once tried manually, to get logged into your stockcharts.com account?

Comment: thank you again @user3666197 for making it much more readable. It looks much better now.

Comment: @user3666197. Yes I tried. that was the very first  thing I checked when I saw the error.

Comment: You may try your code-concept "against" free-charts, if you opt to. Your Proof-of-Concept prototype may be run with `http://stockcharts.com/freecharts/perf.php?[MM]` and many others.

Comment: @user3666197 Yes we do also use other information from stockcharts.com.It is a good website. the information I try to get from [link] (http://stockcharts.com/h-hd/?GOOG) is the historical adjusted stock price/volume information, which is only available for registered users. therefore I must login first and then get the historical adjusted information.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue is not in Python, but rather the `<form <input ...>` syntax

You may want to drill-down into the **current** `stockcharts.com` login-interface.

**`dblogin.php`** expects ( as of 2014-10-12 ) to receive this set of parameters:

1. `form_Name          == "Login"`
2. `zendesk_timestamp`
3. `redirect`
4. `form_UserID        == <<_aText_>>`
5. `form_UserPassword  == <<_aText_>>`
6. `form_RememberMe`

So you need to meet the `php`-interface expectations to get this step farther.

You shall inspect your real-(manual)-login values upon being submitted, blank/empty strings do not work as substitutes.

Comment: I tried, but it still does not work, see updated post. thank you again @user3666197.

Comment: What value do you provide in timestamp?

Comment: an empty string ''. In payload, I used the exact same values except "form_UserID" and "form_UserPassword" as in the original post.

Comment: The types of some fields (like zendesk_timestamp) are "hidden". As @user3666197 pointed out, there might be some specific values for those fields. does anyone know how to to get values for those "hidden" fields? thanks

Comment: As written above: You shall inspect your real-(manual)-login values upon being submitted, blank/empty strings do not work as substitutes.

Comment: how can I get those values? I input user ID & password, and then click "login". is there a way that I can somehow "see" the strings that webpage sends to its server after I click "login"?

Comment: Yes, you may use packet-level sniff or you may relay+route your reverse-engineering code to direct http-protocol-session through an http-urllib decoder/transponder-proxy, to see the [onSubmit POST values]